# Is there an alternative to JXTA for Java P2P frameworks?

Tags: java, p2p, jxta

My team is having trouble with a project using JXTA.

Is there another framework for P2P networks java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Release 2.7 has been significantly improved in terms of testing. And, the Practical JXTA II book has been made available for reading on Scribd. Have a try again.

Answer (score 3):

As you have not described your particular needs regarding functionality, I'd like to offer you our [MsgConnect](http://www.msgconnect.com/) as one of the options. It's available for both SE/EE and for Java Mobile (as well as the number of other platforms and development tools).

Answer (score 2):

You can take a look at the [anthill project](http://www.cs.unibo.it/projects/anthill/), but it's JXTA based.

But if you have trouble with JXTA you should ask question on it. Maybe someone could help you with that.